# Can we Publish component(minor version content) to broker db using TOM.Net API?

Tags: 2013-sp1, tom.net

We have a scenario where the product component is in workflow and publishes the minor version content to Staging/preview site in Product Detail page. There is also Product landing page which uses tom.net API to publish all the products component as json.SO we have the minor version content available in Product detail page and not in product landing page as the component workflow is not completed.It always uses the major content to publish to Broker DB.Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the version you're on? Quite some changes were done to the workflow business logic in 2013 SP1, 8.1 and 8.5

Comment: Not sure if my comment is valid on the version later than 2013 sp1, But are you checking the checkbox saying "If Possible, publish the in-workflow version of an Item" while publishing the components as JSON? You can find the option in Publishing Dialog's "Advanced" tab.

Answer (score 2):

> There is also Product landing page which uses tom.net API to publish all the products component as json

Assuming you are using a standard publish instruction in TOM.NET, you can ask the publisher to "publish minor versions" by using `IncludeWorkflow = true` in the ResolveInstruction (one of the parameters of the publish method).